# How to solve IE7 issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

A site works fine with Chrome, FireFox, IE8 but does not work with IE7 (I do not care about IE6).  Many people appear to still use IE7 so would like to get it to work.

As a new user to this site I can not upload a picture, so I will describe the issue as best as I can.

Within IE7, the search fields in the header are pushed down below the "beans" and the coffee beans are not tiled, it just shows one instance of the image?

Now how does one solve these issues?  Is there a site you can submit a page to which analyses it for incompatibility issues?

Any pointers appreciated thanks.

Comment: welcome to web-development! :) IE's always the sucker here. You will find a lot of inconsistencies. The best thing would be test frequently (while developing) on all engines (ie, webkit, gecko).

Comment: I have no idea where this needs migrated, but definitely not here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Frankie, I thought I had followed all the guidelines correctly.  So is it just a matter of trial and error with IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah IE is really a pain. You can't live with it , can't live without it :(

It will be helpful to add a reset.css which tries to neutralize some if not all of the browser inconsistencies when it comes to style.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/base/

When it comes to javascript it's always helpful to use a JS library like jQuery and Prototype as most of the browser-related quirks are being dealt with the JS Library you choose.

Another technique is to include a css style for particular version of IE.

But yeah, for IE its mostly test,test, test and swear :D

You can also use IE Tester http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage which will help you view the page in different versions of IE.

Comment: Thanks for the [IE Tester ](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage ).Main Fighting On IE is with JavaScript.